# Do you have to retrieve before you update a Dynamics CRM 365 Online entity

Tags: dynamics-365

Typically code that needs to update an entity is as such. (the columns in account might not exist, this is just to make a point)

```
Entity someEntity = new Entity("account");
Guid accountId = "[GUID that you already have from another query]";
ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "name", "address" });
someEntity = organizationProxy.Retrieve(someEntity.LogicalName, accountId, attributes);

someEntity["name"] = "Mister";
someEntity["address"] = "XYZ";
organizationProxy.Update(someEntity);
```

It seems a bit wasteful, that if I was updating 5000 records, I have to query the database for a reference to the entity and then update it. Is there a way, since I already have the record GUIDs to create the entity object and then just update it? Something on the lines of ...

```
Entity someEntity = new Entity("account");
someEntity["accountid"] = accountId;
someEntity["name"] = "Mister";
someEntity["address"] = "XYZ";
organizationProxy.Update(someEntity);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to retrieve before updating. Just do the update straight away, e.g. with the code from the last part of your question.